# Javascript Text-to-Speech is delayed

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am using SpeechSythesisUtterance in Javascript to just say 1 word as it appears on the screen. I need this to be instant, however, I am getting a 1 second delay every time. Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

This is my code:

```
speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
speech.volume = 2;
speech.text = this.word.text;
speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
```

Comment: I don't experience any delay at all.  I think you might need to provide more context-- try making a minimal working version of your code that you can post as an example.  You can insert a "code snippet" in your question that contains HTML, CSS, and JavaScript if needed.  How are you running it?  For example, is the word selected via a form?  More details please.

Comment: Hi Matt, it's not delaying on my phone (chrome browser) but on my laptop (all browsers) it is delayed. I have also received feedback that it is delayed for other people on their laptops. This is all the code there is really, the word is just a string from an array and should run as soon as the word shows on the screen

Comment: I just tried the example on here https://usefulangle.com/post/98/javascript-text-to-speech and it is delayed on my laptop again but not on my phone.